# Prevent security warnings with Facebook "Activity Plugin" code

Tags: facebook, security, warnings

I am trying to fix an issue with Facebook's "Activity Plugin" where when people click through to access an interesting link they see, they first get a Facebook warning saying "warning, leaving Facebook..." and then a bunch of browser pop ups alerting them to insecure content or a mix of content.

The reason this matters is that (in the user's mind!) they're still on my website -- it's blahblah.org and they go "ooh! that blog post looks interesting" and click.  Of course the reality is that when they click on a FB Activity link it's served by FB and the browser thinks it's FB...so I understand why the messages appear.  I just want to know if there's something I can do at my end to ensure that they DON'T appear, or at least that they are minimal and appear as seldom as possible.

I found that some Facebook Connect users had issues and this was caused by their profile photos.  But I didn't see anything specific to the "Activity Plugin" and of course the FB info page has nothing useful.

I'd love some suggestions or ideas.  Surely I'm not the only one who's noticing this issue!!

Thank you!